# Is a dynamic `theme-color` meta tag color possible?

Tags: html, css, meta-tags, chakra-ui

I'm using Chakra UI with Next.js and wanted dynamically change the `theme-color` as user switches color modes.
Using variables do not seem to work.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="var(--theme-color)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you cannot set a dynamic color.
But you can try:

```html
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="cyan" />
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" content="black" />
```

Here is a good article about it https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/